# JSX expressions must have one parent element. Google Maps

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I know that technically the code should be fine, however the VSCode is saying it is wrong.

The issue is this part of the code

```
{this.state.heat.map((item) =>
        <InfoWindow
        key={item.id}
        //onLoad={onLoad}
        position={lat:{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}, lng:{item.location[0].coordinates[1]}}
        ></InfoWindow>
      )}
```

being added to this part

```
 {!this.state.heat ? (<div>Loading...</div>) : (
        <div>
          <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey="XXXX"
      >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */ }
          
         <>
         {this.state.heat.map((item) =>
        <InfoWindow
        key={item.id}
        //onLoad={onLoad}
        position={lat:{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}, lng:{item.location[0].coordinates[1]}}
        ></InfoWindow>
      )}
         </>


        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
      <ul>
     </ul>
    </div>
      
     
      
      )}
```

I don't see anything wrong with the way I have written the code - so why is it saying there is an issue?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect: `position={lat:{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}` If that's meant to be an object (1) you need object delimiters around it (in addition to the `{}`s of JSX) (2) Objects require key-value pairs, but you only put a value there for `lat`. `lng` has the same problem.

Comment: But am able to print them out in a list. So why can’t I put them here?

Comment: `position={}` says that value of position will be dynamic and should be calculated with whatever javascript is given inside the curly braces. So, if you want to provide an object, you will end up with 2 curly braces like so - `position: { {lat:val, lng: val} }`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  this.state.heat.map((item) => (
    <InfoWindow
      key={item.id}
      //onLoad={onLoad}
      position={{
        lat: item.location[0].coordinates[0],
        lng: item.location[0].coordinates[1],
      }}
    ></InfoWindow>
  ))
}
```

In JSX the part in `{}` is treated as code, and `position` is a property that expects an object. So the first layer of `{}` is an indication "This is code" and the second layer of `{}` say "This is an object" and you should follow the syntax of a javascript object inside the second layer of `{}`

Put it in another way

```
      {
        lat: item.location[0].coordinates[0],
        lng: item.location[0].coordinates[1],
      }
```

is valid js syntax and you should put it in another `{}` for the sake of jsx i.e.

```
  {{
    lat: item.location[0].coordinates[0],
    lng: item.location[0].coordinates[1],
  }}
```